# What's the best practice to import external boost in a c++ cmake project?

Tags: c++, boost, cmake

I'd like to import external boost in a c++ cmake project.

I did several tries and finally got the following `CMakeLists.txt` works:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.14)
project(my_project
    VERSION 0.0.1
    LANGUAGES C CXX)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)

include(FetchContent)
FetchContent_Declare(
    boost
    URL https://boostorg.jfrog.io/artifactory/main/release/1.78.0/source/boost_1_78_0.tar.bz2
)
FetchContent_MakeAvailable(boost)

set(Boost_ROOT "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/_deps/boost-src")
set(BOOST_INCLUDEDIR ${Boost_ROOT})

find_package(Boost 1.78)
include_directories(${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS})

add_executable(
    boost_test
    tests/boost_test.cpp)
```

However, I feel a little uncomfortable because `set(Boost_ROOT "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/_deps/boost-src")` looks hacky -- it has a strong assumption that the fetched content will be stored in `_deps` folder, which I rather want to put it in a dedicated folder like `3rd_party` or `external` as typical C++ project layout conventions.

I found there're 2 ways for doing that:

1. Use `FetchContent_Declare` to download the project. However, I don't know how to execute extra build commands to compile non-header-only libraries.
2. Use `ExternalProject_Add` to download and compile the boost project. It looks like an old-fashing way, besides, I don't know how to add boost as part of dependencies to top-level CMakeLists.txt in this way.

The way I adopted is the former one, but I wonder if it's the correct way to include external boost (not system-default installed one) as part of a C++ project, or is there a best practice for doing this?

Any comments, suggestions, answers are welcome. Thanks.

Comment: Is recommend using a package manager like Conan or vcpkg to manage dependencies

Comment: Using _both_ `FetchContent` and `find_package` makes no sense. Just use `find_package` and a fully external package manager, like vcpkg, or the host system's.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to use Boost in a CMake project is like this:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.25)
project(boost-example)

find_package(Boost REQUIRED)

add_executable(myapp main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(myapp PRIVATE Boost::headers)
target_compile_features(myapp PRIVATE cxx_std_11)
```

`Boost::headers` is the library to link to for all of the Boost header-only components. If you need a component that includes a real library, then link to `Boost::<component>`, too, and be sure to name `<component>` after the `REQUIRED` argument to `find_package`.

Don't mess with FetchContent. Your users will know how to get the necessary dependencies. You can provide a `vcpkg.json` file or a `conanfile.txt` to make it easier to use Vcpkg and/or Conan, respectively.